# Get grtexstr ready for Python Qt4

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I try to use a python qt program to insert tex equations into xmgrace. It is called [grtexstr](http://faraday.fc.up.pt/cfp/Members/vpereira/linux-projects/grace-latex-strings), but the problem (i assume) is that it is not compatible with Qt4. I did some changes when loading qt:

```
#from qt import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
```

but I still get a error message

```
File "./grtexstr.py", line 68, in __init__
    QWidget.__init__(self,parent,name,fl)
TypeError: QDialog(QWidget parent=None, Qt.WindowFlags flags=0): argument 2 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
```

when I try to run it. Google brought me to a suggestion to use

```
fl=Qt.WindowFlags(0)
```

in

```
class latexWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent = None,name = None,fl = 0):
        QWidget.__init__(self,parent,name,fl)
```

This does not help either. Is there a python Qt expert out there you can help?

I put the file [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3538352/grtexstr.py) for an easy access.

#### Edit

It seems the problem exists with the type of name, which shouldn't be None.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, `QWidget.__init__()` only takes two parameters in Qt4+, `parent` and `f` (window flags). I'm not familiar with earlier version of Qt, but I'm guessing they've changed the signature to not need a name.

So instead you should call (though see comment below about `QWidget` vs `QDialog`):

```
QWidget.__init__(self,parent,fl)
```

Is `name` what you want shown in the window title bar? You can set that separately with:

```
if name:
    self.setWindowTitle(str(name))
```

Also, why are you calling `QWidget.__init__()` instead of `QDialog.__init__()`, given you are subclassing `QDialog`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is not my code and I never used Qt before, so I don't know why `QWidget.__init__()` is called. I just hoped it wasn't to complicated to port the code from Qt3 to Qt4. I will see if I will get it done. :)

Comment: Cool, well I would suggest changing it to QDialog!